# Getting more info from python sqlite exceptions

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7

I'm using python's builtin [sqlite3 DB module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#).

While inserting objects to my DB tables, following `sqlite` exception raised:

```
"PRIMARY KEY must be unique"
```

As there are different insert methods for each object, I can't say for sure in which table does it failed:

```
import sqlite3
...
class SomeObject1:
....
def _insert_some_object1(self, db_object):
        self._cursor.execute('insert into %s values (?,?,?)' % TABLE_NAME,
        (db_oject.v1, db_object.v2, db_object_v3,))
```

Exception got caught in `main()` by `except Exception as e:`, so it's only info I've got.

I would want to know in which table insertion failed, value that failed, etc...

What's the right way to get the most info from `sqlite` exceptions?

Thanks

Comment: use same id on writing table. Which database allow same id ? Can you create 2 files( with same name)  in same directory ?

Comment: @dsgdfg ,  I know that I inserting same key which should be unique.  My question is about getting more info from sqlite exceptions

Comment: `sqlite exceptions` need reedit your package (isn't good idea). Clear your db table and print `which processed`? This is your code exception not sqlite. if use an id generator check what is wrong. Need check db table `before working`(duplicate,blank values,type etc.). @Samuel

Comment: @dsgdfg I don't think we understand each other :). Bottom line, python module `sqlite3` trew exception and I want to get more info about it. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you using sqlalchemy or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this really all depends on what you are using to connect to the database. Each module will display different errors.

I personally use sqlalchemy, and it gives you detailed errors. Here is an example to show what I mean (note: this is just an example, I personally do not support inline sql):

```
import sqlalchemy

connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///mydb.db')

cursor = connection.connect()

query = "INSERT INTO my_table (id, name) values(1, 'test');"

cursor.execute(query)
```

And the error that is returned:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) PRIMARY KEY must be unique "INSERT INTO my_table (id, name) values(1, 'test');" ()
```

As far as core sqlite3 module, I don't believe it will show the query that was executed. If you don't use a module such as sqlalchemy, then you will need to handle and show the error yourself. Take a look at this as example:

```
import sqlite3


def execute(query):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(query)
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as err:
        print('Query Failed: %s\nError: %s' % (query, str(err)))
    finally:
        conn.close()


execute("INSERT INTO my_table (id, name) values(1, 'test');")
```

And the output on error:

```
Query Failed: INSERT INTO weapon (id, name) values(1, 'test');
Error: PRIMARY KEY must be unique
```

Comment: Thanks Jason I'm using sqlite3 module - https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html @Jason Heine

Comment: @Samuel I've updated my answer to give you a direction on how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Cool, thanx! Going to try that out :)

Answer (score 3):

I have seen some code like   (sqlite3 in python)

```py
try:
  conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
  c = conn.cursor()
  c.execute(query)
  conn.commit()
except sqlite3.Error as err:
  print('Sql error: %s' % (' '.join(err.args)))
  print("Exception class is: ", err.__class__)
```

Comment: Upvoted because it shows how to do exception monitoring for sqlite3-specific errors, not just broad `Exception`.